# Combine two table and create new column in result based second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two temp table, from that want to combine both of them like following.Is there any way to do this? In final result there should consist of  new columns based on second tables Tax Type. The number of tax types is unknown. It could change time to time.

```
Table : Work
    +-----------+----------------+
    |  WorkId   |     Work       |
    +-----------+----------------+
    |  1080     |  "Work One"    |
    |  1081     |  "Work Two"    |
    |  1082     |  "Work Tree"   |
    +-----------+----------------+

Table : TaxDetails
    +--------+----------+---------+---------+
    | Taxid  |  TaxType |    Amt  |  WorkId |
    +--------+----------+---------+---------+
    |   1    |   VAT    |   120.0 |   1080  |
    |   1    |   VAT    |   300.0 |   1081  |
    |   2    |   S.Tax  |   150.0 |   1083  |
    |   2    |   S.Tax  |   101.0 |   1080  |
    +--------+----------+---------+---------+

Final Result :
    +--------+-------------+-------+--------+
    | WorkId |   Work      |   Vat |  S.Tax |
    +--------+-------------+-------+--------+
    |  1080  | "Work One"  |  120.0|   101.0|
    |  1081  | "Work Two   |  300.0|   0.0  |
    |  1082  | "Work Three"|  0.0  |   0.0  |
    +--------+-------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Please, formatted text - not images.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is 300 a S.Tax?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with simple case statements, column aliases and a subselect to get the tax totals.  `ISNULL` will return 0 if no tax values are available for a `WorkID`:

```
SELECT
W.WorkId
,Work
,ISNULL(VAT,0) AS 'VAT'
,ISNULL(Service_Tax,0) AS 'Service Tax'
FROM Work AS W
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT
    WorkID
    ,SUM(CASE TaxType WHEN 'VAT' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS VAT
    ,SUM(CASE TaxType WHEN 'S.Tax' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS Service_Tax
    FROM TaxDetails
    GROUP BY workID
    ) AS T
    ON w.workID = T.WorkID
```

Comment: tax types will change time to time

Comment: I have added a solution based on tax description.

Comment: Need to create column in final result based on tax types in second table and values should be the amount for the corresponding tax types.

Comment: OK think I get what you need now.... this is why it is important to make sure you write a good question straight away.  Please check amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select w.WorkId, w.work
     , isnull(v.Amt,0) as Vat
     , isnull(s.Amt,0) as Stax
from work w 
left join TaxDetails v 
 on v.WorkId = w.WorkId 
and v.Taxid = 1
left join TaxDetails s 
 on s.WorkId = w.WorkId 
and s.Taxid = 2
```

Comment: This answer was flagged, presumably because there is no accompanying text explanation. This answer looks straightforward enough to me that it doesn't require one.